# user selection boxes with login system html

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, authentication

I have a website whereby users login and select a box to reserve their bike. I want to link this to each specific user so that when they click to reserve their bike in the database it is shown that they have reserved this and so if another user clicks on the reserved box to say if it is stolen then an email is sent to that user

```
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl1" class="Control" />
<label id=a1 class="mouseover1" for="btnControl1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl2" class="Control" />
<label id=a1 class="mouseover1" for="btnControl2"></label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghdbc704/

Comment: how does your db table Look ? do you have a form where you submit the selected boxes ?

Comment: No thats what I wanted to know in general for how to make it? My db currently only stores name,email and password

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically want a table for the bikes, and a table for the reservations. In the Reservation you will store the id of the user, the bike and maybe the time and so on.

Then you will have to make a html form with your boxes. And bind the bike id to the boxes, submit them and store them togheter with the userId in the DB

there is a free php Reservation System, which maybe a help for you. It is opensource, and a good place to get an idea about that stuff:
https://github.com/olejon/phpmyreservation